# Variable change in integral with spherical coordinates in $N$-dimensinal space

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates, change-of-variable

I am having difficulty with this problem.
Given $f(x)$ is smooth enough, $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$. The spherical coordinate of $x$ is $x = \left(r, \sigma\right)$, $r = \left\|x\right\|$, $\sigma \in S^{N-1}\left(0,r\right)$. Assuming $f(x) = u(Cr)$, for some constant $C$.
So how can I transform $\int\limits_{B(0,1)}f(x)dx$ to the term of some integral including $u(r)$ respected to $dr$?
I think we can write
$$\int\limits_{B(0,1)}f(x)dx = \int\limits_{0}^1 \int\limits_{S^{N-1}}u(Cr)drd\sigma = \int\limits_{0}^1 u(Cr)dr \int\limits_{S^{N-1}}d\sigma = \int\limits_{0}^1 u(Cr) \cdot 4\pi r^2 dr = 4 \dfrac{\pi}{C^3} \int\limits_{0}^C t^2 u(t) dt.$$
I feel that something does not add up here, but I don't know what it is.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In reducing $\int_{S^{N-1}}d\sigma$ to $4\pi r^2$, you have assumed that the sphere in question is 3D. Since we're working with $N$ dimensions, you need a general formula for the angular integral of an $N$-sphere.

Comment: Suppose we have n-dimensional sphere
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2 \leqslant a^2$$
To obtain, for example, its volume we can use n-dimensional spherical coordinates:
$$\begin{cases}x_1 = r\cos \phi_1, \\
x_2 = r\sin \phi_1 \cos \phi_2, \\
\cdots \\
x_{n-1} = r\sin \phi_1 \sin \phi_2 \cdots \sin \phi_{n-2} \cos\phi_{n-1}\\
x_n = r\sin \phi_1 \sin \phi_2 \cdots \sin \phi_{n-2} \sin \phi_{n-1}
\end{cases}$$
Do you need more help or you can continue yourself?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you for your help, I see it.

Comment: @zkutch Thank you for your help with this. But can you help me more with it? Thanks very much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume element ($d\vec x$ or $dV$) in $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates is $r^{n-1}\, dr\, d\sigma$, where $d\sigma$ is a volume form on $S^{n-1}$. (In the familiar cases, for two dimensions $dx\, dy = r\, dr\, d\theta$ and for three dimensions $dx\, dy\, dz = (\rho^2\, d\rho)(\sin \phi\, d\phi\, d\theta)$.)

So it should be:

$$ \int_{B^n(0,1)} f(x)\, dx = \int_{S^{n-1}} \int_0^1 u(Cr)\, r^{n-1}\, dr\, d\sigma = \frac{1}{C^n} \int_{S^{n-1}} d\sigma \cdot \int_0^C t^{n-1} u(t)\, dt $$

The unit [hypersphere volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Relation_with_surface_area) is

$$ \int_{S^{n-1}} d\sigma = \frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} $$

or in equivalent forms for even and odd $n$,

$$ \int_{S^{2k-1}} d\sigma = \frac{2 \pi^k}{(k-1)!} $$
$$ \int_{S^{2k}} d\sigma = \frac{2 (k!) (4\pi)^k}{(2k)!} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Comment: @aschepler on link mentioned by you formula $\int_{S^{n-1}} d\sigma = \frac{n \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$ is without $n$ in nominator, correct?

Comment: @zkutch $\frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} = \frac{n \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$. But not sure why I had that version rather than the slightly simpler one which is right in the link.

Answer (score 2):

I know, that the answer is done and accepted, but I would like suggest one fine way, different from suggested by me in comments (I started it and have yet hidden), in hope it will be useful for somebody.

Firstly suppose we would like to calculate volume

$$V_n=\int\limits_{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2 \leqslant R^2}dx_1\cdots dx_n$$

Taking new coordinats $x_1=R\xi_1,\cdots, x_n=R\xi_n$ it's easy to obtain $$V_n=\beta_nR^n$$
where $\beta_n$ is volume of $n$-dimensional sphere with radius $1$.

Then we will have
$$\beta_n=\int\limits_{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2 \leqslant 1}dx_1\cdots dx_n=\int\limits_{-1}^{1}dx_n\int\limits_{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2 \leqslant 1-x_n^2}dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}$$
On right hand side inner integral is $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere with radius $\sqrt{1-x_n^2}$ and, therefore, is equal to $\beta_{n-1}\big(\sqrt{1-x_n^2}\big)^{n-1}$. Now using famous [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) we  have
$$\beta_n = \beta_{n-1}\cdot \sqrt\pi \cdot\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2} \right)} =\cdots = \frac{\pi^{\frac n2}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1 \right)}$$
where we used $\beta_1=2$.

Comment: Thank you for your nice way.